# Ignoring exceptions for a specific amount of time

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, python-requests

Trying to make the `try` to run in a loop, since I am booting a machine containing the webserver and I want to make it run and not just go direct to the except and stop the script. I have made a while for the http-status code, but that does only work if the machine is up.

So my question is how can I make the `try` loop for like 5 minutes before it goes to the `except`? Sorry for my poor explanation.

```
try:
    r = requests.head("http://www.testing.co.uk")

    while r.status_code != 200:
        print "Response not == to 200."
        time.sleep(30)
        r = requests.head("http://www.testing.co.uk")

    else:
        print "Response is 200 - OK"

except requests.ConnectionError:
    print "NOT FOUND - ERROR"
```

Comment: If you're sleeping for 30 seconds and you want to keep trying for 5 minutes, you'll have to loop 10 times, right ?

Comment: If the connection is refused, you get an exception. Did you mean you wanted to keep on looping for 5 minutes before giving up altogether?

Comment: Correct, because it goes straight to the exception if the webserver is down. So I want to make it loop for 5 minutes for before it goes the exception. @MartijnPieters

Comment: The loop for checking http-code isn't the problem, but the exception, since it goes direct to the exception and stops if the webserver isn't up. I want to make it loop for 5 minutes before it stops. @alfasin

Comment: @Iknowpython: no, you cannot postpone the exception. I think you want to *keep looping* even if there was an exception each time. You want to *retry* for 5 minutes when there is an exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you reopen this?  The code has more errors than listed in the referenced question and will surely lead to a follow-up -- I have an answer that does a good job describing a better pattern.

Comment: So there is no way to loop for example  5 minutes before it breaks ?

Comment: You can catch the exception, and inside the `except` block, decide whether to ignore it, or re-throw it, "breaking" it.

Comment: Could you please show how? @jedwards

Comment: Do I have to have a except? without it it wont run.

Comment: @jedwards: reopened, with the right reserved to have it re-closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import requests, time, datetime

# Determine "end" time -- in this case, 5 minutes from now
t_end = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

while True:
    try:
        r = requests.head("http://www.testing.co.uk")

        if r.status_code != 200:
            # Do something
            print "Response not == to 200."
        else:
            # Do something else
            print "Response is 200 - OK"
            break  # Per comments

        time.sleep(30)  # Wait 30 seconds between requests

    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print "NOT FOUND - ERROR"
        # If the time is past the end time, re-raise the exception
        if datetime.datetime.now() > t_end: raise e
        time.sleep(30)  # Wait 30 seconds between requests
```

The important line is:

```
if datetime.datetime.now() > t_end: raise e
```

If the condition isn't met (less that 5 minutes have elapsed), the exception is silently ignored and the while loop continues.

If the condition *is* met, the exception is [re-raised](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to be handled by some other, outer code or not handled at all -- in which case you'll see the exception "break" (in your words) the program.

The benefit of using this approach over something like (instead of `while True:`):

```
while datetime.datetime.now() > t_end:
```

is that if you find yourself outside of the while loop, you know you got there from `break` and not from 5 minutes elapsing.  You also preserve the exception in case you want to do something special in that case.

Comment: Thanks that works. How can I get it out of the loop if it gets http-code 200?

Comment: Just add `break` inside the `else` block

Comment: @Iknowpython updated the answer to show you the break statement

Comment: Big Thanks for your help and making me understand how to do it.

Comment: @Iknowpython its likely going to a different exception, that block only catches exceptions of type `requests.ConnectionError` -- is that what you're getting?